# Error 503 (Service Unavailable) on old server after moving with cPanel Transfer Tool

Tags: dns, cpanel, http-status-code-503

I used cPanel's Transfer Tool to move my websites to a new IP address. It was a temporary move and I wanted to revert back to my old server today. First thing I noticed was the transfer tool changed all the A records for all sites. I changed these back using [swapip](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/scripts/the-swapip-script/), and then tried accessing the sites. They load for a very long time and finally fail with:

> Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your
> request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try
> again later.
>
> Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

From numerous threads, I realized 503 usually occurs when System PHP-FPM is on. However, I didn't set this on niether before nor after moving. I didn't change any other settings except the DNS, so I'm guessing it should be a DNS issue, not sure if DNS issues can cause 503 errors. I've been struggling with this for a day now.

Checking Apache Error log, I see attempts to connect to the server I temporarily moved to:

> [proxy_http:error] [pid 1659:tid 47454830633216] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to [new.ip.address]:443

Answer (score 0):

After a few days digging, I found my mistake and how to rectify it thanks to the cPanel Support. I thought it worthwhile sharing in case anyone else faces the same problem:

First, I had to [disable the live transfer feature](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360055505054-How-to-disable-Live-Transfer-by-default) before doing the transfer. It prevents the tool from disabling IPs and proxying domains.

Given I hadn't I had to [rever the changes the tool had made](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360051936854-How-do-I-revert-the-changes-made-by-the-live-transfer-feature-in-the-transfer-tool-), which basically involved running the following scripts from the command prompt:

```
$ whmapi1 unset_all_service_proxy_backends username=$USER
$ /scripts/xfertool --unblockdynamiccontent $username
$ whmapi1 unset_manual_mx_redirects domain=domain.tld
```

The link above explains what each of these scripts does.